# How to navigate to another page after using a provider function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I have created a function in my Login provider to verify OTP for my app like below.

```js
Future<bool> verifyOtp(String otp) async {
    final _loginData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _status = await AuthApi.verifyOtp(otp);
    _isLoading = false;
    _name = _loginData.getString('name');
    notifyListeners();
    return _status;
  }
```

Now whenever I am trying to use this on my code like below,

```js
final bool status = await Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).verifyOtp(verificationCode);

// ignore: avoid_print
print("STATUS ==== " + status.toString());
if (status) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/discover');
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Incorrect OTP!!!")));
}
```

It's giving me an exception like below -

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.)
```

Anyone please guide me, what is the actual way to navigate from a provider. I am very new in Provider. Thank you so much :)

----- Full Provider Code is Below -----

```js
class LoginProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _status = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isOtpScreen = false;
  String? _name;

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  bool get isOtpScreen => _isOtpScreen;
  String? get name => _name;

  void sendOtp(String phone) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _status = await AuthApi.sendOtp(phone);
    _isLoading = false;
    _isOtpScreen = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> verifyOtp(String otp) async {
    final _loginData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _status = await AuthApi.verifyOtp(otp);
    _isLoading = false;
    _name = _loginData.getString('name');
    notifyListeners();
    return _status;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your login provider and UI page code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a GlobalKey you can access from anywhere to navigate

**Create the key**

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**Pass it to your App:**

```
new MaterialApp(
  title: 'MyApp',
  onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
);
```

**Use in your route:**

```
    print("STATUS ==== " + status.toString());
    if (status) {
       Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).pushReplacementNamed('/discover');
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content:
      Text("Incorrect OTP!!!")));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final bool status = await Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).verifyOtp(verificationCode);

// ignore: avoid_print
print("STATUS ==== " + status.toString());
if (status) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/discover');
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Incorrect OTP!!!")));
}
```

change this code to the next one and i think it will work
but you must add this code in build function if it's stateless widget

```
final provider = Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context);

final status = await provider.verifyOtp(verificationCode);

// ignore: avoid_print
print("STATUS ==== " + status.toString());
if (status) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/discover');
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Incorrect OTP!!!")));
}
```

this will work fine with you i hope it help you

Comment: Okkk. Now I got it. It wasn't on the build function. That's why it isn't working. Thank you so much.